# Synchronization triggered by file changes

Tags: windows-7, sync

My data is stored on a server and accessed via a network drive. The server is sometimes down, so at the moment I'm using windows' offline folder synchronization. However I'd prefer using a local copy of my files and have it synchronized to the net drive to decrease local access time. Since **I'm the only user accessing my data**, a usual synchronization that starts with scanning through all files for changes seems overhead (and takes too much time), I'm looking for a **synchronization tool that somehow gets notified as soon as a file is changed locally** and then directly synchronizes it. Freeware that can be used without admin priviledges would be prefered.

Comment: related: [Alternative to Dropbox (on my server)?](http://superuser.com/q/128590/35237) and [Which is the best application to Sync two folders?](http://superuser.com/q/13493/35237)

Answer (score 0):

What about [SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C26EFA36-98E0-4EE9-A7C5-98D0592D8C52&displaylang=en) as one of the related questions suggests?

Comment: does that only sync when a file is actually changed? Oh well, I'll try to convince my admin...